# Playing Audio Files in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can anybody please tell me how can I play these audio urls.

http://www.toucheradio.com/archivesplayer.php?q=15192&host_id=58

http://www.toucheradio.com/archivesplayer.php?q=15186&host_id=28

I tried in Mediaplayer but came to know that only .wmv,wma and .mp3 only plays in mediaplayer.Can anyone please give me any idea of playing these files.

ManyThanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if your trying to play streaming channels, you could use the [Windows Phone Streaming Media](http://phonesm.codeplex.com/)
from `CodePlex`.

You could have a look at these threads:

[Windows Phone 8 - Playing streamed audio (internet radio station)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541390/)

[can't play shoutcast ip with port with backgroundAudio on Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370117/)